# How do I stop the player partly going through ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a controller for a 2d character, I fixed the issue of the player jittering through the wall but I cant fix the player jittering through the ground. Got this code from multiple tutorials and tweaking stuff. If you have any tips that would be greatly appreciated I'm new to this stuff and working on my first game (had to ramble cuz I put too much code) thanks.

```
{
    public float speed, height;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool horizontalRight = false;
    private bool horizontalLeft = false;
    private bool verticalMove = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            horizontalRight = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            horizontalLeft = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            verticalMove = true;

        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (horizontalRight == true)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            horizontalRight = false;
        }
        else if (horizontalLeft == true)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            horizontalLeft = false;
        }
        if (verticalMove == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, height);
            verticalMove = false;

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: 百闻不如一见 "Hearing something a hundred times isn't better than seeing it once"

Comment: @Margus wait what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate continuous collision detection on your rigid bodies, it'll keep them from phasing through things so long as they're being moved via their velocity.

Answer (score 0):

A typical jump in unity would look like:

```
void Jump()
{
    if (_isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * _jumpSpeed);
        _isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

and in collision event

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision hit)
{
    _isGrounded = true;
}
```

this would limit when you can use a jump.